# add option to messaging attach menu

Tags: android

Is there a way to add to the list of items that can be attached in the SMS / Messaging app? i.e. right now there's Pictures, Capture Picture, Videos, ..., Record audio, Slideshow.

I'd like to listen to some intent in my own application to provide its own attachable object - is this possible?

ACTION_GET_CONTENT (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT) seems close, but it looks to be in the other direction, i.e. picking content from my app.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (SmsAppImplementation app : thousandsOfSmsApps) {
  app.contactDeveloperAndAskIfTheySupportThis();
}
```

If by "the SMS / Messaging app" you mean [this app out of the AOSP](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms), then there is no documented API for working with it, and based on the source code it would appear that they handle each of those attachment types manually themselves.